# Unable to import testng results into Xray Cloud using github actions workflow

Tags: testng, testng.xml, jira-xray

The YML file I have used in my project is
[image]

The error I get in the workflow build

[image]

Surefire results path mentioned in both the images is correct but still, I don't understand why it is unable to import the results.

Comment: FYI: This is the documentation I followed https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Integration+with+GitHub

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you have referenced I'm assuming you are using the Cloud version of Xray.
If it is the case please make sure you are using the XRAY_CLIENT_ID and XRAY_CLIENT_SECRET in the username/password fields (more info here: https://github.com/mikepenz/xray-action).

Comment: Hi I'm using the same, I don't get problem with the authentication, issue is with results importing.

Comment: FYI `ℹ️ Configured XrayCloud
        ℹ️ Start logging in procedure to xray
        ℹ️ Completed login and retrieved token`

Comment: Can you share the testng-results.xml file?

Comment: I would recommend that you get the testng-results.xml file and try to upload it by hand, using "curl" for example, as mentioned in https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST+v2#ImportExecutionResultsRESTv2-TestNGXMLresults , to see the exact error you get. You have to make an initial authentication request to obtain the auth token, as mentioned in: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Authentication+-+REST+v2

Comment: Just checking in if you were able to overcome this? If not, have you tried my previous suggestion?

Comment: <attribute name="summary">
           <![CDATA[testSignIn]]>
         </attribute> <!-- summary -->
            <attribute name="test">
              <![CDATA[]]>
            </attribute> <!-- test -->
            <attribute name="description">
              <![CDATA[This will test sign in]]>
            </attribute> <!-- description -->
            <attribute name="requirement">
              <![CDATA[BB2-83]]>
            </attribute> <!-- requirement -->
            <attribute name="labels">
              <![CDATA[SIGNIN]]>
            </attribute> <!-- labels -->

Comment: Hi @Sérgio I tried using Curl Command, and I get this error **{"error":"Import results request timed out! The import task is still running on the background."}**

Comment: I think there was a performance spike and that now things should back to normal. If you still face issues using the curl command then I would recommend reach out to Xray support team here: https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest version of [xray-action](https://github.com/mikepenz/xray-action/releases) , as there was a fix on version v2.4.2 to change the Xray Cloud URL that changed meanwhile.
You should use the latest version, which currently is v2.4.5.
Meanwhile the [tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Integration+with+GitHub) on Xray side was also updated.

Comment: Hi Tried with latest version 2.4.5 but the error remains the same, I have a question though is it because of the surefire-report xml report and not a direct testng report, does that make any difference ?

Comment: if you have a testng-results.xml, it's a TestNG XML based file, so the problem is not from that. you big is your testng-results.xml file?

Comment: Sorry couldn't understand your question properly. The results are present in the testng-results.xml file.

Comment: what is the file size in KB of the testng-results.xml file? and how many tests have you run to have an idea of the dimension?

Comment: Just one test. it's 8KB in size. can you send me your email id. I will send the xml file to you through email.